# SQLite grouping

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have a query:

```
select a,count(b) from xyz group by a;
```

This gives me the number of occurrences of each different value of 'a' in my table. My question is how can I query the same values but now grouped by another filed 'c'?

Ex:

For population:

```
(b;c;a)
1;2;test1
2;4;test1
3;4;test1
4;4;test1
5;3;test2
5;3;test2
```

I'd like to get:

```
(field 'a';number of occurrences for each value of 'c';total of occurrences for 'a')
test1;2;4 
test2;1;2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean "number of distinct occurerences of 'c'" then try:

```
select a, count(distinct c), count(*) 
from xyz
group by a;
```